# unity gone, no desktop. struggle to get back

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

after update, unity is gone. Only wallpaper en desktop icons is showing. I've tried several suggestions, but I struggle to open terminal with the keys cntrl+alt+t. Nothing happens. What else can I do to restore everything back? I'm running ubuntu 12.04 lts. I realise that this may look like a duplicate. But I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

try to go through tty1 by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 and install gnome from there :

```
apt-get install gnome
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've tries it, but get a lot of errors. It is supposed to be connected to the internet. There a command to change to another source? There also a command to restore or go back to a previous state?

Answer (score 0):

to get to the terminal, resatart your computer, and hold "shift" before the ubuntu logo. Then select the "Ubuntu Recovery Mode" You will beable to acess a root terminal but it won't let you write onto the disk, but if you select "dpkg" and enter your password, you can then edit the disk. Then go back and select "root" then enter `sudo apt-get gnome-shell` for the gnome desktop enviroment, or `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` for the kde desktop. Try H.Omar's answer first, because it it simpler.